# Dynamically return all SQL results where the value of one column equals the value of another column

Tags: jquery, sql, dynamic

I've got a search form that looks through a table for employees. I only want the employees that match the SupEmp to be returned in the search. The person doing the search has an EmployeeNumber. That employee number is dynamically imported when you sign into the search form. If your **EmployeeNumber** matches other **SupEmp numbers**, then display all rows that match your EmployeeNumber.

Currently my code just returns all employees. The revised code should only show the employees whose SupEmp matched your EmployeeNumber.

```
var vendorCols = "SupEmp, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EmployeeNumber, DEPARTMENT, Position, Status";

       $('#EmployeeLookup').autocomplete({
           source: function (request, response) {
               var sql = "SELECT " + vendorCols + " FROM EMPLOYEE_SEARCH"
                   + " WHERE UPPER(FIRST_NAME + LAST_NAME) like '%" + request.term.toUpperCase() + "%'";

               $.ajax({
                   url: '/public/GetData',
                   type: 'POST',
                   data: JSON.stringify({ query: sql, connectionName: "LawsonConnection" }),
                   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                   dataType: 'json',
                   success: function (dataArray) {
                       response($.map(dataArray, function (item) {
                           if (request.term.indexOf("'") >= 0) { item = 'Do not enter special characters' }
                           if (item === "Data Not Found")
                               item = "Employee Cannot Be Found";
                           return {
                               label: item
                           };
                       }));
                   }
               });
           },
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of blanks on your question, but from what I understood, you need to add an AND clause to your query and considering you have a list **SupEmp numbers**, it should be something like:

```
+ " WHERE UPPER(FIRST_NAME + LAST_NAME) like '%" + request.term.toUpperCase() + "%'"
+ " AND EmployeeNumber IN (" +request.SupEmpNumbers,.join(', ') + ")" ;
```